# Only one object is being saved in a text file using java.io

Tags: java, list, object, java-io

I started developing an app for my class, which has a request that I need to save objects from a list in a .txt file. It seems to be working, but when I do that, it saves only one object that I entered. I don't know what the solution is. My code is below. P.S. I am using gui to add my objects in a list.

```
List<Korisnik> listaK=Kontroler.vratiObjekatKontroler().vratiKorisnika();
   try {
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.txt"));
          ObjectOutputStream out= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
          for (int i = 0; i < listaK.size(); i++) {
             out.writeObject(listaK.get(i));
             out.close();
          }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < listaK.size(); i++) { 
    out.writeObject(listaK.get(i)); 
    out.close(); 
}
```

You are closing the output stream once you have written the first object. This way you cannot write anything else into it. Move the `out.close()` out of `for` loop.

Comment: my god, i seem to be going crazy. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You are closing your stream inside the for loop. I recommend:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
ObjectOutputStream out = null;

try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.txt"));
    out= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    for (int i = 0; i < listaK.size(); i++) {
        out.writeObject(listaK.get(i));
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (out != null) out.close;
    if (fos != null) fos.close;
}
```

Comment: I think it's time for `try-with-resources` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hoping that you are using at least Java SE 7 :) you can take advantage of [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html) so you don't need to care about closing "resources":

```
try ( 
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.txt"));
     ObjectOutputStream out= new ObjectOutputStream(fos)
 ){
      for (int i = 0; i < listaK.size(); i++) {
         out.writeObject(listaK.get(i));
      }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The **try-with-resources** statement contains the `FileOutputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` object declarations that are separated by a semicolon. When the block of code that directly follows it terminates, either normally or because of an exception, the close methods of the `FileOutputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` objects are automatically called in this order. Note that the close methods of resources are called in the opposite order of their creation.